# Clipping region for OnEraseBkgnd differs from clipping region for OnPaint

Tags: mfc

I'm writing an mfc application.
I've a simple `CWnd` with `OnEraseBkgnd` and `OnPaint`. I'm experiencing some problems when another window covers partially my window.

So When the covering window is being moved out my `CWnd` gets `WM_ERASEBKGND`. I'm cleaning up dirty area and I return `TRUE`. What I can see here is that `CDC` I get has clipping box set and I use it so only a covered part is being erased. That's good.

But then `WM_PAINT` comes. `CDC` I get with `GetDC` **does not** have any clipping box so the whole window area is being repainted. This is a problem because in my paint event I use `CDC::DrawText` with a transparent background (`CDC::SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT)`) and painting the same text in the same not-erased place causes that text becomes 'bold'. Simply painting text over and over in the same place without wiping out background makes it look ugly.

Is it a normal behavior? Is my approach ok?

**EDIT:**

Here I attach more inforamtion about issue.

SSCCE:

```
class Foo : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
    {
        CRect rect;
        pDC->GetClipBox(rect);

        HBRUSH brush = ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
        HGDIOBJ pOld = pDC->SelectObject(brush);

        const BOOL result = pDC->PatBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);

        pDC->SelectObject(pOld);

        return result;
    }

    void OnPaint()
    {
        CWnd::OnPaint();

        CDC *dc = GetDC();

        CRect clipBox;
        dc->GetClipBox(clipBox);

        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(rect);

        CFont *font = &globalFont;                 // in my app here is the font I use but it doesn't matter
        HFONT hFont = static_cast<HFONT>(font->GetSafeHandle());

        auto oldFont = dc->SelectObject(hFont);
        const int bkMode = dc->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);               
        dc->DrawText("AAAAAAAAA", -1, rect, 0);
        dc->SetBkMode(bkMode);
        dc->SelectObject(oldFont);
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Creation:

```
Foo* f = new Foo;
f->Create( 0, "test", WS_VISIBLE| WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
```

Below how does the window look normally:

[image: normal]

And below after moving the window so half of the text was out of monitor and then moved back:

[image: not quite normal]

So the part of window which was invisible was erased and then text was placed again. For the visible part of the window text was not erased and in `OnPaint` was redrawn again causing 'bold'.

Comment: It might help if you give more information. What are the creation flags for this window and the other window (popup, child, etc.)? Which are the parents of this window and the other window and what is the relation? ---- In regards to some text changing to bold, maybe it's related to clear-type formatting, it doesn't become bold, but the text gets a little heavier because you are writing over it without erasing the previous text.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've added code and screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `CPaintDC`, not just because it controls resources, as Barmak pointed out, but also because it retrieves clipping data. `GetDC` does not do that. (Barmak also mentioned `PAINTSTRUCT`, but it may not be clear that is the key to the clipping issue.)

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated issue, but `GetDC` is causing GDI resource leak in above code. `ReleaseDC` must be called before exiting the function:

```
void OnPaint()
{
    CWnd::OnPaint();
    CDC *dc = GetDC();
    dc.DrawText(...);
    ...
    ReleaseDC(dc);
}
```

Better yet, MFC has automatic cleanup with `CClientDC`

```
void myWnd::foo()
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    dc.DrawText(...);
}
```

`OnPaint` can use special `CPaintDC` class which corresponds to `PAINTSTRUCT`:

```
void myWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); //don't call CWnd::OnPaint
    dc.DrawText(...);
}
```

**Back to the problem:**

It looks like part of background is not repainted, but part of the text is repainted. This makes it look ugly specially with clear type fonts (it looks like bold but it isn't).

You can fix the problem with this:

```
dc.SetBkMode(OPAQUE);
dc.SetBkColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));
dc.DrawText(L"AAAAAAAAA", -1, rect, 0);
```

Another option: override `OnEraseBkgnd` and force it to do nothing:

```
BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC*)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Do all of the painting in `OnPaint()`

```
void myWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    dc.FillSolidRect(rect, ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW) );

    CFont *font = &globalFont;
    auto oldFont = dc.SelectObject(font->GetSafeHandle());
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.DrawText(L"AAAAAAAAA", -1, rect, 0);

    dc.SelectObject(oldFont);
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer, however I still don't understand why doesn't it work properly. I can have workarounds, but that's not a point I think.